# Named Pipes data loss on deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I'm embedding a Unity application in a WPF page, and am using Named Pipes to pass data between the parent and child applications. However, for one of the variables I'm passing, I am experiencing data loss.

I am serializing the data (in this case, a `List<String> shelfNumAndStatus`):

```
IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
server = new NamedPipeServerStream("CENSORED", PipeDirection.InOut, 1);
f.Serialize(server, shelfNumAndStatus);
```

I am deserializing in a similar manner:

```
client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "CENSORED", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None, TokenImpersonationLevel.None);
IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
List<String> ShelfData = (List<String>) f.Deserialize(client);
```

However, before serialization the data has 326 rows, and after serialization it has 276. Is there a way to make sure that the entire data is being serialized, and it is all being deserialized to prevent this?

Comment: Does calling Flush on the pipe after serialize make a difference?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for the response, I just tried adding both server.Flush() and client.Flush() which seemed to have no effect

Comment: Is this data loss consistent? So if you make a small List (say 20 rows), what happens? What are characteristics of the lost 50 strings?